# How to find nginx logs in an Alpine Linux container

Tags: nginx, find, alpine-linux, busybox

I have an Alpine Linux container running nginx. I am getting 502 errors in my browser when I try to visit localhost to see my app.

In order to find out more, I decided to look at the logs. After logging into my container's busybox shell, I ran the following three commands:

```
cd /
find . -iname "*nginx*log*"
find . -iname "*log*nginx*"
```

But I am failing to find anything. How can I find out where these logs live?

Comment: The default names are `access.log` and `error.log`.

Comment: That found it. Thanks!